# Hidden file input Python Selenium

Tags: python, html, selenium

I am facing an issue when trying to upload a file to a hidden file input using Python Seleniun. To be clearer please see the image below.

[Issue example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d4zNe.png)

I uploaded one file myself for the first field. 
Below a sample of the corresponding HTML code before and after the upload.

```html
<judge-upload caption="Output to be scored" is-uploading="submissionsCtrl.isUploading[$index]" ng-model="submissionsCtrl.newSubmissions[$index].submissionBlobKey" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-scope ng-not-empty" aria-invalid="false" style=""><div class="hcj-upload">
  <md-input-container class="md-input-has-value">
    <div class="hcj-upload-label ng-binding">Output to be scored</div>
    <div class="hcj-upload-content" ng-switch="!ctrl.fileKey">
      <!-- ngSwitchWhen: true -->
      <!-- ngSwitchWhen: false --><div ng-switch-when="false" layout="row" class="ng-scope layout-row" style="">
        <div>
          <input value="example0.out" aria-label="Filename" readonly="" class="md-input" id="input_8"><div class="md-errors-spacer"></div>
        </div>
        <div>
          <button class="md-icon-button md-button md-ink-ripple" type="button" ng-transclude="" ng-click="ctrl.onClear()" aria-label="Clear">
            <md-icon class="ng-scope material-icons" role="img" aria-hidden="true">delete</md-icon>
          </button>
        </div>
      </div><!-- end ngSwitchWhen: -->
    </div>
  </md-input-container>
</div>
</judge-upload>

*************************************

<judge-upload caption="Output to be scored" is-uploading="submissionsCtrl.isUploading[$index]" ng-model="submissionsCtrl.newSubmissions[$index].submissionBlobKey" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-scope ng-empty" aria-invalid="false"><div class="hcj-upload">
  <md-input-container class="">
    <div class="hcj-upload-label ng-binding">Output to be scored</div>
    <div class="hcj-upload-content" ng-switch="!ctrl.fileKey">
      <!-- ngSwitchWhen: true --><div ng-switch-when="true" layout="row" class="ng-scope layout-row">
        <button class="md-raised md-primary md-button md-ink-ripple" type="button" ng-transclude="" ng-click="ctrl.onUploadClick($event)" ng-disabled="!ctrl.ready || ctrl.fileName" aria-label="Upload">Upload file</button>
        <input class="hcj-upload-input ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid md-input ng-empty" ng-model="ctrl.fileValue" aria-label="Input file" id="input_3" aria-invalid="false" type="file"><div class="md-errors-spacer"></div>
        <div class="hcj-upload-filedrag layout-align-center-center layout-row" layout="row" ng-show="!ctrl.fileName" layout-align="center center" drag-drop="" on-drag="ctrl.onDragOver($event, $enter)" on-drop="ctrl.onDrop($event)" aria-hidden="false">
          or drop file here
        </div>
        <div class="hcj-upload-loading ng-hide layout-align-center-center layout-row" layout="row" ng-show="ctrl.fileName" layout-align="center center" aria-hidden="true">
          Uploading file. Please wait.
        </div>
      </div><!-- end ngSwitchWhen: -->
      <!-- ngSwitchWhen: false -->
    </div>
  </md-input-container>
</div>
</judge-upload>
```

Using selenium I tried various solutions to upload the file but none of them work :

```
driver.find_element_by_id("input_3").send_keys(PATH)
driver.execute_script('document.getElementById("input_4").setAttribute("value",PATH)')
```

After the second one, the html seems to be updated with the file path but it doesn't display it in the web browser.

Could you please help me on this ?

Thanks !

**------ EDIT ------**
When I send the files using the second method the issue I have is that the submit button is still disabled. The code of the button looks like

```html
<button class="md-primary md-button md-ink-ripple" type="button" ng-transclude="" ng-click="submissionsCtrl.createSubmission()" ng-disabled="!submissionsCtrl.canUploadSubmissions()" disabled="disabled">Submit</button>
```

I tried to enable it through Python code but it has not worked at the moment, still working on that if you have any idea.

```
driver.execute_script('document.getElementsByClassName("md-primary md-button md-ink-ripple")[0].disabled=false')
driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@ng-click='submissionsCtrl.createSubmission()']")[0].click()
print driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@ng-click='submissionsCtrl.createSubmission()']")[0].is_enabled()
```

The output still shows False for is_enabled even after the script call and the click on the button does nothing.

**------ EDIT 2 ------**
I finally suceeded to enable the button and click on it. Unfortunately it looks like the files are not really sent by the form.

I am still investigating on why the files are not sent.

The code I used to enable the button :

```
driver.execute_script('''document.evaluate("//*[@ng-click='submissionsCtrl.createSubmission()']", document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue.disabled=false''')
driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@ng-click='submissionsCtrl.createSubmission()']")[0].click()
```

Comment: Your attempt using `execute_script` is looking for `input_4` instead of `input_3`? Is there any way you could give a link to the actual website to look at?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It's just because they are several inputs and I wanted to test them simultaneously. The webpage is on https://hashcodejudge.withgoogle.com/ but sadly you cannot see it without registering to the competition.

Comment: Did you try and upload the file even though the browser was not showing the text in the field after the `execute_script` placed the path in the **value**?

Comment: If you want to test the UI upload feature, this is a good use case. If you just want to upload a file or test that one CAN upload a file to the endpoint, I would recommend uploading the file using an HTTP request using the requests or urllib libraries. Much faster.

Comment: @PixelEinstein Thanks for your answer. I tried this but the button is disabled due to the files not being loaded. I tried to enable the button manually but didn''t succeed yet. I'll add the corresponding code to the original post.

Comment: @Aphid Thanks for your answer. Actually the issue I have is that I have no idea what is the HTTP call done. I don't think I have a way to simply POST the form.

Comment: Refer to the Network tab of your browser dev tools and see what request is being sent to upload the file. All an upload is is a request to the server with file data, you can mimic that request in code and perform it using the aforementioned libraries as long as you have the right authentication (usually headers or cookies).

Answer (score 0):

Because your page is AngularJs page, the file input is bind to model `ng-model="ctrl.fileValue"`.

Even you use `execute_script` to set the value in background way, but this way not trigger the model `fileValue` change.

I guess the click event `ng-click="ctrl.onUploadClick($event)"` of `UPLOAD FILE` button, will obtain the file path from model `fileValue`, rather than from `document.getElementById("input_3").value`.

So you should not succeed to upload the file even there is no error report.

To resolve your issue, the only way is to change the value of model `fileValue` directly:

```
def input_upload_file_path(file_control, file_path):
    script = '''
       angular.element(arguments[0]).scope().$apply('fileValue=arguments[1]')
    '''
    driver.execute_script(script, file_control, file_path)

file_control = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#input_3')
file_path = <absolute path of file>

input_upload_file_path(file_control, file_path)
```

After execute `input_upload_file_path()`, add a pause at here, then you can check the function work fine or not by execute below Javascript in Browser DevTool's Console Tab:

```
angular.element('#input_3').scope().$eval('fileValue')
```

Should print the same file path as argument value of `input_upload_file_path()`

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer.
I tried this but I think that it didn't do anything, the file is not getting uploaded in the input and running the JS script in the console gave me an error : 

Uncaught Error: [jqLite:nosel] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.4-local+sha.617b36117/jqLite/nosel
    at third_party.js:42
    at Object.X [as element] (third_party.js:64)
    at <anonymous>:1:9